# Is it possible to access window10 bitlocker encrypted partition in ubuntu with TPM?

Tags: encryption

I have a laptop installed both windows10 and ubuntu. The windows partitions are encrypted by the bitlocker. If I understood the windows manual correctly. The bitlocker fetches key from TPM and decrypt the partitions. I want be able to access these partitions when boot into ubuntu. After searching on www I found solutions via using recover key. However I do not want to expose this key to any user. So I wonder is possible to let ubuntu bitlocker tools do the same thing (fetching key from TPM) as bitlocker does on windows?

The windows will automatically take the ownership of the TPM. Thus if the machine is not actually boot into the windows which set it up, the TPM will refuse to give out any key. I wonder, is it possible to let the TPM trust other OS installed on the same machine? I guess we have to do some manual setting in the TPM console to add some key hold by other OS for example ubuntu.

Here is a reference of [taking ownership of the TPM](https://github.com/fox-it/linux-luks-tpm-boot). But I think this will cause the TPM forgetting bitlocker's key.

Comment: Ubuntu has no bitlocker tools, it has many other encryption tools but not that one which is Microsoft proprietary so the answer is no, not a chance.

Comment: the dislocker somehow can decrypt the bitlocker partition with recover password (Is this the same key give out by the TPM?).

Comment: According to this (https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2020/06/unlocking-bitlocker-volumes-by-booting-from-a-usb-drive/):
If the TPM is all that you have (that is, no Recovery Key is available in the AD, the user’s Microsoft Account or as a file/printout), unlocking a volume by booting from a USB drive will not be possible. This is specialized tool for recovering Bitlocker data and is explicitly discards the possibility of recovering a TPM only protected drive from another OS on the same machine.